# How do I get a unique set of values for a specific key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, unique-values

I'm using Python 3.8.  If I want to get a unique set of values for an array of dictionaries, I can do the below

```
>>> lis = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
>>> s = set( val for dic in lis for val in dic.values())
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

However, how would I refine the above if I only wanted a unique set of values for the dictionary key "a"?  In the above, the answer would be

```
{1, 3}
```

I'll assume that each dictionary in the array has the same set of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```py
lis = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
# assuming the variable key points to what you want
key = 'a'
a_values = set(dictionary[key] for dictionary in lis)
```

I hope I've understood what you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @alani, Thank you for spotting my error, coding in dart for a while has me syntactically scrambled.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
lis = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
search_key = 'a'
s = set(val for dic in lis for key, val in dic.items() if key == search_key)

print(s)

#OUTPUT: {1, 3}
```

Use the `dic.items()` instead of `dic.values()` and check where the `key` is `a`.

Another way to do it to simplify the things:

```
lis = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]
search_key = 'a'
s = set(dic.get(search_key) for dic in lis)

print(s)
```